# ruby ENV['ANDROID_HOME'] says nil, but it's set

Tags: android, ruby

I've got an ANDROID_HOME variable set:

```
$ set | grep ANDROID_HOME
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jenkins/android-sdk-macosx
```

However when I start ruby, it's not seeing it:

```
$ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > ENV["ANDROID_HOME"]
 => nil
```

It is seeing other variables however:

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > ENV["HOME"]
 => "/Users/jenkins"
```

The ANDROID_HOME variable is defined in my ~/.profile .

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `export` the variable otherwise it won't be visible in any child processes:

```
export

Set an environment variable. Mark each name to be passed to child 
processes in the environment.

Syntax
      export [-fn] [-p] [name[=value]]
```

So in your `.profile`:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/android-sdk-macosx
```